# How to make image header on the top of NavigationView?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

How could I make a header on the top of NavigationView in Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls (UWP app) ?

I managed to make header using PaneHeader property, but I would like to have the graphic above the menu button.

```
<muxc:NavigationView.PaneHeader>
    <Image Source="Resources/header.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="45"/>
</muxc:NavigationView.PaneHeader>
```

This is the result I have:

[image]

And this is what I expect:

[image]

Comment: I tested the full screen mode and it displayed fine in full screen mode, may I ask what is the scenario on your side?

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use [Title bar customization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/ui-input/title-bar) to get the effect you want. Add the image in the custom title bar.

#### MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="48"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="AppTitleBar" Background="Transparent">
        <Image Source="Assets/header.png" 
       Grid.Column="1"
       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
       Width="200" Height="50"
       Margin="8,0,0,0"/>
    </Grid>

    <muxc:NavigationView Grid.Row="1"  IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed">
        <muxc:NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <muxc:NavigationViewItem Content="A"/>
            <muxc:NavigationViewItem Content="B"/>
            <muxc:NavigationViewItem Content="C"/>
        </muxc:NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame"/>
    </muxc:NavigationView>

</Grid>
```

---

#### MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    var coreTitleBar = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar;
    coreTitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;

    // Set XAML element as a drag region.
    Window.Current.SetTitleBar(AppTitleBar);
}
```

#### UPDATE

```
private void NavigationView_PaneClosed(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationView sender, object args)
{
    imgTest.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}

private void NavigationView_PaneOpened(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationView sender, object args)
{
    imgTest.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It is the way to handle the problem, but will not work in full screen mode. Additionaly, it would be good to hide the image when the navigation is collapsed, so that is why I thought about placing the image in navigation header.

Comment: Please check my UPDATE in answer, can this meet your needs? use the PaneOpened, PaneClosed event to change the Visibility property of the image.

Comment: I tested the full screen mode and it displayed fine in full screen mode, may I ask what is the scenario on your side?